# Integrate Auth0 CustomDatabase and Passwordless

Tags: authorization, registration, auth0, password-less

looking for an advice how to properly integrate Custom Database and Passwordless (magic-links) approach on Auth0.

We're using Custom Database integrated with PostgreSQL, but our users asking for "magic links" approach (as on Slack auth flow).

According to Auth0's documentation, **Custom Database** and **Passwordless** are different "databases of users", and can't be integrated between.

Does anyone had any approach to generate magic-links to authenticate users automatically from Custom Database?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

I wanted to reach out and confirm that there is no out of the box solution for allowing Custom Databases and Passwordless integrate with one another. I hope this helps confirm your findings as you continue on with your quest. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You would need to a Passwordless connection in Auth0 (Passwordless Email because Passwordless email would not save the user's email) and then add [Account Linking](https://auth0.com/docs/link-accounts) Rule which will detect verified accounts with the same Email and merge them into one, with possibly the Custom DB account as primary account and Passwordless email account as secondary. The user can choose to log in using eighter option.

The account linking rule is highly customizable too and you can even roll out your own Account linking logic using Management API which allows for Linking/Unlinking accounts: https://auth0.com/docs/api/management/v2#!/Users/post_identities